# AngularJS JSON not arriving php

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am having the following problem, i have a service that makes a http request, and when i try to get the response throws a parser error, and that is because the response is not ready when it tries to parse the response.

here is the code

```
simpafAPIservice.getSimulacao($stateParams.id).success(function(response){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(response[0].info));
         $scope.simuladorInfo.cliente = response[0].cliente;
         $scope.simuladorInfo.info = JSON.parse(response[0].info);
         console.log(JSON.stringify(response[0].info));
         setTimeout(function(){
             for(var i=0;i<$scope.simuladorInfo.info.simuladores.length;i++){
                 $scope.addDataGraphic(i);
             }
         },100);
     });
}
```

When i console.log the response it prints an empty string, which is odd, that's why it throws this parser error.

My question is how can i do .success function only when the response is ready?

Edit:

in the end the problem is other, i am storing a JSON in a database, but when the JSON has very information it doesn't arrive at php.

here's my php code:

```
    <?php

$id = $_POST["id"];
$id_col = $_POST["id_col"];
$tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
$cliente = $_POST["cliente"];
$info = $_POST["info"];

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
$data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

require 'connection.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($id!=""){
    $sql = "UPDATE `Simulacoes` SET `info`='".$info."' WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Simulacoes`(`id_col`, `tipo`, `data`, `cliente`, `info`) VALUES ('".$id_col."','".$tipo."','".$data."', '".$cliente."', '".$info."')";
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo $info;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

here's the response i get:

```
{"data":"","status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"params":{"id_col":"1","tipo":"Património Reforma","info":{"simuladores":[{"nome":"ii","info":{"prazoReforma":20,"empreendimentos":{"empreendimentos":[{"id":"1","nome":"Oporto Place","localizacao":"Porto","$$hashKey":"object:50"}],"tipologias":{"0":"Loft","19":"T2","37":"T3"},"plantas":{"0":"3.1","1":"6","2":"8","5":"3.2","12":"2.1","13":"7","14":"2.2","15":"5"},"pisos":[{"id":"2","piso":"1","$$hashKey":"object:69"}]},"entrada":"20000","duracao":"35","taxa":"5","montante":82000,"prestacao":"414","prestacao_seguros":"440","renda_liquida":"320","resultado":-120,"patrimonio":134367},"$$hashKey":"object:38","imovel":{"empreendimento":{"id":"1"},"tipologia":"Loft","planta":"3.1","piso":"2","info":{"condominio":"50","renda":"400  ","preco":"102000  ","id":"1"}},"hide":1}],"montanteTotal":134367,"pensao":"569","idadeActual":"45","idadeReforma":"65","pmII":120,"pmTotal":120}},"url":"php/guarda-simulacoes.php","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

As you can see, when i echo $info it returns nothing, an empty string, but in data.config.params i get all params. Anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: A [promise](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that link helped a lot. I will try this.

Comment: in the end the problem is other, i am storing a JSON in a database, but when the JSON has very information it doesn't arrive at php, anyone knows why?

Comment: but this only happens online, when i am working on localhost it works fine.

Comment: What status are you getting? 500?

Comment: when i store my info i am not getting this information. how can i get it?

Comment: I am getting status 200, which is ok, right?

Comment: Yes that sounds OK. So status 200 and no body. I suggest you've got a problem at your server end that needs fixing. Use a packet sniffer or log your PHP responses to a file to inspect what you're sending out.

Comment: it's very odd because when i store the info i get a status 200 and in data.config.params i get all params that i sent but when i echo one param i get an empty string, and i am not overriding it anywhere. What is going on?

Comment: You're really going to have to add some more information to your question so others can see what your trying to do. The PHP code at your server end would be useful, as well as this whole "data.config.params" business and a dump of the response packet would be invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), $http.success returns data in the first argument, which is converted to JSON only if the active transformResponse can detect is is the appropriate format:

> Angular provides the following default transformations:
>
> ...
>
> Response transformations
>   ($httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse and
>   $http.defaults.transformResponse):
>
> If XSRF prefix is detected, strip it (see Security Considerations
>   section below). If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a
>   JSON parser.

If your server is responding with an empty string (which seems the case here)
then it will not be detected as a JSON object and will remain an empty string.

Check your server response, it may be responding with no body and an error status. One thing to watch for if you are requesting data from a different domain (even if it's ultimately the same server) is [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Your codes looks ok, which is taking promise from And executing code in its success. I think instead of `setTimeout` you should use `$timeout` which will run `$digest` cycle when timeout complete

**Code**

```
simpafAPIservice.getSimulacao($stateParams.id).success(function(response){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(response[0].info));
         $scope.simuladorInfo.cliente = response[0].cliente;
         $scope.simuladorInfo.info = JSON.parse(response[0].info);
         console.log(JSON.stringify(response[0].info));
         $timeout(function(){
             for(var i=0;i<$scope.simuladorInfo.info.simuladores.length;i++){
                 $scope.addDataGraphic(i);
             }
         },100);
     });
}
```